# Transform scale of polygon pattern fills with Carto/Mapnik

Tags: mapnik, cartocss, mapbox-studio

In CartoCSS you can specify an SVG pattern fill for a polygon as so:

```
#layer {
    polygon-pattern-file: url(images/fill.svg);
}
```

However, the size of the fill is too big at small scales and too small at large scales, and I would like to apply a custom transform to the fill to ensure that it scales properly. Looking at the documentation for [polygon-pattern](https://github.com/mapbox/carto/blob/master/docs/latest.md#polygon-pattern) it appears that you can only change the scaling of the polygon being filled, not the actual fill itself.

Is there a way to apply a custom scale to SVG pattern fills? Essentially, it is applying an SVG `transform=scale()` to the main group of the SVG and changing the root element's height and width.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Update**: CartoCSS now supports this since version 0.17.

While Mapnik's PolygonPatternSymbolizer should support this since Mapnik 3 CartoCSS does not yet support this property on polygon or line patterns.

An example for Mapnik XML support can be found [here](https://github.com/mapnik/test-data-visual/blob/master/styles/geometry-transform-translate-patterns-svg.xml#L15) or see the related [Mapnik issue](https://github.com/mapnik/mapnik/issues/1010).

I would suggest opening a feature request at the [mapbox/carto](https://github.com/mapbox/carto) repository on GitHub. The [mapnik/mapnik-reference](https://github.com/mapnik/mapnik-reference) repository will also need updating.

Comment: I have created issues at the relevant repositories: [mapbox/carto#445](https://github.com/mapbox/carto/issues/445) and [mapnik/mapnik-reference#120](https://github.com/mapnik/mapnik-reference/issues/120).